# Autodetect modem in Linux?

Tags: hardware, modem

Is there a way to autodetect modem devices in Linux and then symlink them to `/dev/modem` using a udev rule?

Currently, I wrote a program that probes each serial port, sending `AT` and waiting for `OK`. I have a udev script that runs this for every ttyS and ttyUSB device. However, I've now been informed that there's other devices, such as OBD-II diagnostic bridges, that also speak with AT commands.

Comment: Also if it's a serial printer then your AT command is going to get printed on paper, which isn't good either.  Serial ports predate plug and play, and so were not designed to be able to do auto detection.

Comment: @psusi The issue is USB->Serial converters don't always appear in the same order; you can't permanently say the modem will be `/dev/ttyUSB1` for example.

Comment: The USB->Serial converter should have a serial number or other unique USB identifier you can check.

Answer (score 2):

You could play a little with **cts**, **rts** or other serial status lines and check if the modem responds to lowering/raising that signal correspondingly. But your modem may be configured to ignore these lines, or there might be other devices that also react to those changes.

I think psusi got the correct answer.

I remember I once debugged `hylafax` to get the idea how it derived the type of modem. Basically it did the same as you did - send AT-commands and check the "typical" answer.

Answer (score 1):

Detect the properties of each serial port.  Look at the vendor and model strings.  For example,

```
# udevadm info --query="property" --name=/dev/ttyUSB0**

UDEV_LOG=3
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/orion-ehci.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/ttyUSB0 /tty/ttyUSB0
MAJOR=188
MINOR=0
DEVNAME=/dev/ttyUSB0
SUBSYSTEM=tty
ID_PORT=0
ID_PATH=platform-orion-ehci.0-usb-0:1:1.0
ID_VENDOR=FTDI
ID_VENDOR_ENC=FTDI
ID_VENDOR_ID=0403
ID_MODEL=FT232R_USB_UART
ID_MODEL_ENC=FT232R\x20USB\x20UART
ID_MODEL_ID=6001
ID_REVISION=0600
ID_SERIAL=FTDI_FT232R_USB_UART_A40135O1
ID_SERIAL_SHORT=A40135O1
ID_TYPE=generic
ID_BUS=usb
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:ffffff:
ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
ID_USB_DRIVER=ftdi_sio
ID_IFACE=00
ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Future Technology Devices International, Ltd
ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC
DEVLINKS=/dev/char/188:0 /dev/serial/by-path/platform-orion-ehci.0-usb-0:1:1.0-port0 /dev/serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_FT232R_USB_UART_A40135O1-if00-port0
```